# Does appengine throw AccessControlExceptions when I've tried to do something disallowed?

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using an opaque library which I'm not sure can work on appengine.  I'm just testing out various classes to see what happens, and one particular method causes a AccessControlException to be thrown:

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM.0)
```

There's no stack trace or any other information.  Would this exception be thrown if the library tried to do something that appengine doesn't allow, like starting another thread, writing to a file, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I deployed to the production servers and got a much more specific message:

```
Google App Engine does not support Runtime.removeShutdownHook
```

So, I guess the answer is "yes."

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't seen the App Engine class whitelist:

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html